# Impossible to initialize Elixir

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm starting with Elixir and SQL Alchemy. I've created a python file connecting with a Mysql database to but as soon as I execute with python I get the error bellow:

```
root@raspberrypi:/Python/mainFlask/yonkiPOPS# python yonki.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yonki.py", line 1, in <module>
    from elixir import metadata, Entity, Field
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Elixir-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/elixir/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from elixir.entity import Entity, EntityBase, EntityMeta, EntityDescriptor, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Elixir-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/elixir/entity.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.orm import MapperExtension, mapper, object_session, \
ImportError: cannot import name ScopedSession
```

I have been looking for it but I don't find the reason. This is the yonki.py file:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            from elixir import metadata, Entity, Field
from elixir import Unicode, UnicodeText   
from elixir import *
class User(Entity): 
        username = Field(String(64))

metadata.bind = 'mysql://root:nomasandroid42@localhost/yonkiPOPS'
session.bind.echo = True
setup_all()
create_all()
```

I think that it's maybe due to a required module not installed but I don't know which one.

Comment: Improve your accepte rate first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open the ./elixir/entity.py, find the import line like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import ScopedSession, \
```

then adjust it to:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session as ScopedSession, \
```

Answer (score 15):

Elixir 0.7.1 seems to be incompatible with the latest version of SQLalchemy, 0.8. You can solve that problem with

```
sudo pip install SQLAlchemy==0.7.8
```

Answer (score 2):

seems like sqlalchemy 0.8 changed the location of ScopedSession

http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/ticket/121

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to still be able to update your libraries from the repositories, or don't have root access to change the file, just use this in your file:

```
import sqlalchemy.orm
sqlalchemy.orm.ScopedSession = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session
```

before

```
from elixir import *
```